# How to filter a list down to items matching supplied suffix using Streams in Java 8

Tags: java, java-stream

I am new to Java streams but need to master by practice really!

The collection input is made up of strings e.g. [name][dot][country], example as follows:

```
 - JAMES.BRITAIN
 - JOHN.BRITAIN
 - LEE.BRITAIN
 - GEORGE.FRANCE
 - LEON.FRANCE
 - MARSELLE.FRANCE
 - KOFI.GHANA
 - CHARLIE.GHANA
```

Given a list of countries,
How do I return a list of items whose suffixes matches the supplied countries

So, if I supplied a list parameter containing Britain as item , the resulting list should be:

```
 - JAMES.BRITAIN
 - JOHN.BRITAIN
 - LEE.BRITAIN
```

In the real code the streams statement below gives me the list to be filtered i.e.:

```
List<String> allSolrCollections =  (List<String>) findAllCollections()
                    .getJsonArray(SOLR_CLOUD_COLLECTION)
                    .getList()
                    .stream() 
                    .map(object -> Objects.toString(object, null))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

That is:

```
 - JAMES.BRITAIN
 - JOHN.BRITAIN
 - LEE.BRITAIN
 - GEORGE.FRANCE
 - LEON.FRANCE
 - MARSELLE.FRANCE
 - KOFI.GHANA
 - CHARLIE.GHANA
```

But, I had to use the following non-stream code to filter by suffice name:

```
private List<String> getCollectionsFilteredBySuffices(List<String> listParam, List<String> allItemsList) {
         
        List<String> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String country: listParam) {
             for (String item: allItemsList) {
                if (item.endsWith(country)) {
                    finalList .add(item);
                }
            }
        }
        return finalList ;
    }
```

Can I do both logic in a single java stream statement e.g.

```
 List<String> allSolrCollections =  (List<String>) findAllCollections()
                        .getJsonArray(SOLR_CLOUD_COLLECTION)
                        .getList()
                        .filter(//all items with suffices matching content of list param)
                        .stream() 
                        .map(object -> Objects.toString(object, null))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Is all your data presented in a form of `[NAME.COUNTRY]`? I.e., a name, followed by a dot, followed by a country name?

Comment: Yes, they are Fureeish. Thanks for the prompt response

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the implementation, your method would be more performant if you generate a `HashSet` of prefixes. That would allow to check each element in the list against this set in constant time.

To achieve it with streams, you need to apply [`filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) operation, which expects a `Predicate` and would retain in the stream those elements for which the *predicate* would be evaluated to `true`.

Since your data has a structure `[name][dot][country]`, you can use regular expression `"[^.]*\\."`, which matches zero or more symbols *distinct from a dot* followed by a *dot*, to extract the suffix that corresponds to a country.

That's how it might be implemented.

```
private List<String> getCollectionsFilteredBySuffices(List<String> listParam,
                                                      List<String> allCollections) {

    Set<String> suffixes = new HashSet<>(listParam);
    
    return allCollections.stream()
        .filter(s -> suffixes.contains(s.replaceAll("[^.]*\\.", "")))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // or .toList() for Java 16+
}
```

Here's a single-statement solution (if you want the code to be consice at all costs):

```
return allCollections.stream()
    .filter(s -> listParam.contains(s.replaceAll("[^.]*\\.", "")))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Hello Alexander, the suffixes supplied is unique. and I was thinking of doing the filtering by suffice in one single stream statement.

Comment: @Mege Sure that's doable, but it would increase the time complexity. I've pointed out that in the very first statement of the answer (checking against a `List` is an **O(N)** operation, while checking against a `HashSet` would cost **O(1)**).

Comment: @Mega If you want to have only single stream-statement in your code - see addition at very end of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Alexander, but can I have a filter e.g.  allCollections.stream() .filter(//all items with suffices matching content of list param), as stated in my original question.

Comment: Wow, interesting. I will try that and revert.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. I have added logic to convert the string objects in the listParam and the allCollections to lower case, so filter is not case sensitive.

Comment: allCollections.stream().map(String::toLowerCase)
    .filter(s -> listParam.stream().map(String::toLowerCase).contains(s.replaceAll("[^.]*\\.", "")))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: Can the logic of converting cases by improved on?